# Phone gap app with Sencha Touch and Cordova

Tags: android, extjs, cordova, sencha-touch

I already have a phone gap application which uses Cordova and Sencha Touch that runs in IOS. I am trying to convert that to android. I created a new Project and installed all files as described [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android). The app loads and it renders properly in my device. But the index.html was refereing to

```
`<script type='text/javascript' src='js/cordova-ios-2.5.0.js'></script>`
```

I changed that to the file cordova file I found within the android folder of the Phonegap download. Now its referring to

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/cordova-2.5.0.js'></script>
```

But now its not showing any other controls. just the index page with default background image. Do I have to make some other changes to make it run in android?

This is the first time I am doing a sencha+coredova+phonegap application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the newly updated docs for [Sencha Touch 2.3](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/guide/cordova) which discuss Sencha's integration with Cordova.